# Get Prolog to give all possibilities for arithmetic

Tags: prolog, constraints, constraint-programming, constraint-satisfaction

I was wondering whether in prolog it is possible to get it to brute force all the  possible calculations for something like this:

```
6 is Z + Q

Z = 1 Q = 5
Z = 2 Q = 4
Z = 3 Q = 3
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The generate-and-test approach also works. Of course, you still need some constraints, for example:

```
?- between(1, 6, X), % X is an integer between 1 and 6
   between(1, 6, Y), % Y is an integer between 1 and 6
   X =< Y,           % X is not larger than Y
   X + Y =:= 6.      % the sum is 6
X = 1, Y = 5 ;
X = 2, Y = 4 ;
X = Y, Y = 3 ;
false.
```

The order of the subqueries is significant, so you could as well call it generate-then-test. If you are not afraid to hard-code some of the constraints, there might be ways to avoid generating some of the values, and make some of the tests unnecessary, for example:

```
?- between(1, 6, X), % X is an integer between 1 and 6
   between(X, 6, Y), % Y is an integer between X and 6
   X + Y =:= 6.      % the sum is 6
X = 1, Y = 5 ;
X = 2, Y = 4 ;
X = Y, Y = 3 ;
false.
```

You should realize that going down that road far enough is about the same as implementing a constraint solver like CLP(FD) for example.

Answer (score 3):

I suggest to use, if your Prolog support it, a Finite Domain solver.

I usually use GProlog and I can obtain what you ask with something like

```
fd_domain([A, B], 1, 100),
6 #= A + B,
fd_labeling([A, B]),
```

where `fd_domain/3` set the domain for variables `A` and `B` (from `1` to `100`), `6 #= A + B` set the constraint (`A + B` is 6) and `fd_labelling/1` get all possibles calculations.

In Swi-Prolog is a little different.

First of all, you have to load the CLP(FD) library with

```
:- use_module(library(clpfd)).
```

To set the variables and the domain, you can write

```
Vars = [A, B],
Vars ins 1..100,
```

Setting the constraint is equal

```
6 #= A + B,
```

and to get all possible combinations, you can write

```
label(Vars),
```